# Finding $f(-1)+\lim\limits_{x\to-1}g(x)$

Tags: calculus

I was able to get all of the answers but the last. I got $f(-1) = 1$,
$\lim\limits_{x\to-1}g(x)= 2$, so $1+2=3$, but it was wrong.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Note that there's an small open circle at $x = -1$ for $f(x)$ to show that $f(x)$ is not continuous and that $f(-1) \neq 1$. Instead, $f(-1) = 3$ as you can see from the small red dot at $(-1,3)$. Thus, you have

$$f(-1) + \lim_{x \to -1}g(x) = 3 + 2 = 5 \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Answer (score 1):

f(-1) is different from 'lim x Approaches (-1) of f(x)'. Limit is the value that f(x) approaches to be continuous at that point, whereas actual value can be different from the limit. This unmatch of limit and actual value makes the function discontinuous (as in your graph of f(x) ).

In your case f(-1) = 3
But, 'lim x Approaches -1 of f(x)' = 1.